# How to select a single record in a left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to select a specific model from the Models table using its key ModelID. I also need to add a blurb of content from the Model_Content table. The Models_Content table, however, has several blurbs of content for each model. I need to select just the first blurb.

My tables look like this:

```
 Models // table
 ModelID // pk
 Model // varchar

 Models_Content // table
 ContentID // pk
 ModelID // fk
 Content // varchar

 SELECT M.ModelID, M.Model, C.Content
 FROM   Models M LEFT JOIN Models_Content C ON M.ModelID =  C.ModelID
 WHERE      M.ModelID = 5
```

How do I adjust my query to select just the very first blurb of content for a specific model?

Comment: "First" is one with lowest `ContentID`?

Comment: @Martin, yes. The lowest ContentID will the one I want.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
 SELECT
   M.ModelID, M.Model, C.Content
 FROM
   Models M
 LEFT JOIN
   Models_Content C
     ON C.ContentID = (SELECT MIN(ContentID) FROM Models_Content WHERE ModelID = M.ModelID)
 WHERE
   M.ModelID = 5
```

Or

```
;WITH sorted_content AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ModelID ORDER BY ContentID) AS itemID,
    *
  FROM
    Models_Content
)
 SELECT
   M.ModelID, M.Model, C.Content
 FROM
   Models M
 LEFT JOIN
   sorted_content C
     ON  C.ModelID = M.ModelID
     AND C.itemID  = 1
 WHERE
   M.ModelID = 5
```

Comment: I didn't try your top solution, but it looks really simple. I understand it.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, you solution is the one I needed. I definitely wanted to return multiple models each with a single content blurb. The other query used TOP 1, so it only returned a single model, which is NOT what I wanted.

Comment: cte solution is good, IMHO, coz works when 'Models_Content' table has no own primarykey id field and no extra subqueries occur

Comment: unfortunately, It's too slow on 200k table, totally impossible

Comment: @vladkras Then you need appropriate indexing.  Such as a composite index of `(ModelID, ContentId)` on Models_Content.

Comment: thx! this should be part of your answer, otherwise such queries are extremely slow (while they are best solution)

Comment: The first solution works well for me - thanks! On some big tables with a lot of data, I found it was a little slow, but since (at least in my case) the MIN value returned doesn't seem to matter, I changed the SELECT MIN to SELECT TOP 1 - this cut my overall query (which also does some other joins) down from 70 seconds to about 6.

Answer (score 14):

Sean's answer is the best specific solution but just to add another "generalised" solution

```
SELECT M.ModelID,
       M.Model,
       C.Content
FROM   Models M
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                    FROM   Models_Content C
                    WHERE  M.ModelID = C.ModelID
                    ORDER  BY C.ContentID ASC) C
WHERE  M.ModelID = 5
```

Comment: +1 : I haven't worked with MS SQL Server for a while.  I always forget how much I love to use APPLY :)  ***[Oh man am I a geek...]***

Comment: I've never used APPLY, but it seems simple.  I'll keep this solution in mind. Thanks!

Comment: @Evik - `OUTER APPLY` is a bit RBAR but it can work out more efficient in the case that you have many items in `Models_Content` for a particular Model. The general name for this type of query is "Greatest n per group". [Itzik Ben Gan discusses some approaches here](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/departments/optimizing-top-n-per-group-queries)

Comment: @Martin SMith - Surely `APPLY`'s RBARness *(I'm making more words up today than I care to count)* depends on the query?  I've often seen cases where applying an inline table valued function to be extremely efficient.

Answer (score 4):

```
 SELECT TOP 1 M.ModelID, M.Model, C.Content
 FROM   Models M LEFT JOIN Models_Content C ON M.ModelID =  C.ModelID
 WHERE      M.ModelID = 5
 ORDER BY C.ContentID ASC
```

Comment: Using `TOP 1` works fine with the current WHERE clause, but doesn't generalise to multiple models at once.

Comment: I discovered that the TOP 1 wasn't giving me what I wanted. I failed to mention that I needed to retrieve multiple models each with just a single blurb of content.  Your answer was helpful though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Change your `JOIN` to:

`LEFT JOIN (SELECT ModelID, MAX(Content) as Content FROM Models_Content GROUP BY ModelID)`

This is assuming you don't care which `Content` you get.

Comment: Actually, I do care about which content I get. I should have made the clear in the question.  Thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

you could select the `MIN ( contentID )`

Answer (score 0):

*This may be an expansion on Randy's answer, but it's not completely clear to me.*

For performance reasons I wanted to minimize the number of `SELECT` statements in my query, so I used a `MIN` statement within the primary select instead of within the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    table_1.id AS id, 
    table_1.name AS name,
    MIN(table_2.id) AS table_2_id 
FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_2.table_1_id = table_1.id
-- additional JOINs and WHERE excluded
GROUP BY table_1.id, table_1.name
LIMIT 5
```

There may be tradeoffs depending on the total amount of data. IDK. My query needs to tunnel into the data from a condition several steps removed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it directly on SQL server, but if you use Azure to access the SQL server you can use U-SQL which allows you to use `ANY_VALUE`. it will return one value from a random row of the joined table.

```
SELECT M.ModelID, M.Model, ANY_VALUE(C.Content)
FROM   Models M 
LEFT JOIN Models_Content C ON M.ModelID = C.ModelID
WHERE      M.ModelID = 5
```

or, in case you need it for all models

```
SELECT M.ModelID, M.Model, ANY_VALUE(C.Content)
FROM   Models M 
LEFT JOIN Models_Content C ON M.ModelID = C.ModelID
```

more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/functions/aggregate/any-value

Comment: MySQL answer for SQL Server question?

Comment: @MatBailie I missed the sql-server tags. thanks, i will fix the answer, just a sec!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  M.ModelID
      , M.Model
      , (SELECT TOP 1 Content 
         FROM Models_Content 
         WHERE ModelID = M.ModelID 
         ORDER BY ContentId ASC) as Content
FROM    Models M 
WHERE   M.ModelID = 5
```

Comment: This will not even parse since the `Content` field isn't in your subquery.

Comment: Oh come on, and what if the TOP 1 from Models_Content is for the wrong model!?

Comment: I updated that one, thanks. But i don't think i deserve down vote for this

Comment: @Meen - then you are wrong.  Wrong answers get downvoted, that's how it works.  And your edit doesn't make it correct, see Dems' comment

Comment: Dems, that's why I am joining with modelid

Comment: @Meen - if you don't understand relational databases then please don't post answers here.

Comment: @Meenaksi - You are choosing the first record from Model_Content ***before*** joining on the ModelID.  This means that you could (likely would) randomly choose a record that isn't for the specified model, and thus get no data joined at all.  *Even if there really is a legitimate record in there.*

Comment: @JNK everyone makes mistakes, I am sorry for my part.